# What does 'splat dollar less' (*$<) mean?

Tags: ruby

```
# splat.rb
p *$<
```

Then

```
> echo 'Hello World' | ruby splat.rb
"Hello world\n"
```

What does `*$<` shortcut mean? And what other shortcuts exist?

```
p *$<.class
# IO
p *$<.to_s
# ARGF
```

PS:

```
p $<
# #<IO:<STDOUT>>
```

Comment: Apparently, it means `ARGF` (you know what that is, right?). And the splat is irrelevant here. It's just `$<`. Also try `$>`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, without splat it will return `#<IO:<STDOUT>>`

Comment: What's your ruby version?

Comment: `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7KxsQXi9

Comment: Yes, sorry. `echo 'Hello world' | ruby -e 'p $<'` returns `ARGF` and `echo 'Hello world' | ruby -e 'p *$<'` returns `Hello World`